# Move a row into another sheet if cells do not match

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a small piece of code which will move a row to sheet2 if: G<>M "OR" I<>0 OR L<>R

For example in my made up table below:

```
G   I   L   M   O   R 
1   2   3   1   2   4
```

So this particular row would be moved to sheet two as one of the statements was satisfied: L<>R

I have this code so far:

```
 Sub SingleTradeMove()
 lastRow = Sheets("Trade data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:AK600").ClearContents
 For i = 2 To lastRow
 If Sheets("Trade data").Cells(i, "J").Value = "" Then
 Sheets("Trade data").Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets
 ("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

 End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume `GILMOR` starts in column A. Change column references as needed.

```
Sub SingleTradeMove()

 Dim wsTD as Worksheet
 Set wsTD = Worksheets("Trade data")

  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:AK600").ClearContents

  With wsTD

     lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     For i = 2 To lastRow

        If .Cells(i, "J").Value = "" Or .Cells(i,"A") <> .Cells(i,"D") _
            Or .Cells(i,"B") <> .Cells(i,"E") _ 
            Or .Cells(i,"C") <> .Cells(i,"F") Then 

           .Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy _ 
               Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

         End If

     Next i

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out! :)

Comment: Works well but I had one question, If I wanted to use the left function on cells B and E for example using left(B,4) and left(E,4) these do not work for me. How could I rewrite to incorporate these two things?

Comment: `Or .Left(Cells(i,"B"),3) <> Left(.Cells(i,"E"),3)` ... change 3 as need... you may want to wrap in `UCase()` if case sensitivity is an issue